# How to simplify this derivative.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am going over a problem in a textbook and I'm having some trouble seeing how this simplifies:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x+1}}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x+1}(2x) - x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}}{x+1}$$

How does this become:
$$ = \frac{3x^2 + 4x}{2(x+1)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

Can someone show me how to do the second derivative too? I'm a bit stuck on longer derivations.

Comment: How does $\dfrac{\frac 3 8 + \frac 7 {12}}{1 + \frac 1 2} $ become $\dfrac{23}{36}\text{?}$ The smallest common multiple of $8,$ $12,$ and $2$ is $24,$ so do this: $$ \begin{align} & \frac{\frac 3 8 + \frac 7 {12}}{1 + \frac 1 2} = \frac{24\left(\frac 3 8 + \frac 7 {12}\right)}{24\left(1 + \frac 1 2\right)} = \frac{\left(24\cdot \frac 3 8\right) + 24\left( \frac 7{12} \right) }{(24\cdot1) + \left(24\cdot \frac12\right)} \\  \\ = {} & \frac{(3\cdot3) + (2\cdot7)}{24+12} = \frac{23}{36}. \end{align} $$ Do the same thing, except the smallest common multiple is $2\sqrt{x+1}. \qquad$

Comment: Really?  Three upvotes for a question expecting us to do the work for the asker?

Comment: Please, practice the stuff you learn, this is no "do my homework, *now*" site. You'll always have problems without practice, I'm afraid.

Comment: eh, this is an opinion. I do practice, but sometimes I don't see the solution.

Comment: In pre-calculus you should be able to do algebraic simplifications as e.g., $ \dfrac{x+b/c}{d} = \dfrac{cx+b}{cd} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x+1}(2x) - x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}}{x+1}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{x+1}\left(\frac{4x(x+1)-x^2}{2\sqrt{x+1}} \right)=
$$
$$
=\frac{4x^2+4x-x^2}{2(x+1)\sqrt{x+1}}=\cdots.
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: multiply numerator and denominaor by $$2\sqrt{x^2+1}$$